# pjsip Project Compile 'make dep'

Tags: android, makefile, compilation, pjsip

I want to compile the project and I take an issue on `'make dep'`. I have **Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS x64**.

I configured the file `'config_site.h'` at path `.../pjproject-2.10/pjlib/include/pj`:

```
#define PJ_CONFIG_ANDROID 1
#include <pj/config_site_sample.h>
```

I run the commands

```
export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=.../android-ndk-r13b
export NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.9

NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.9 TARGET_ABI=arm64-v8a ./configure-android --use-ndk-cflags
```

and when I run `'make dep'` I take this issue:

```
/src/pjmedia-audiodev/android_jni_dev.c:36:10: fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory
36 | #include <jni.h>
   |          ^~~~~~~
```

**FIX**
If I change the file 'android_jni_dev.c' like:

```
36 | #include <usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include/jni.h>
```

I get error:

```
../src/pjmedia-audiodev/android_jni_dev.c:38:10: fatal error: sys/system_properties.h: No such file or directory
   38 | #include <sys/system_properties.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: So.... what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that the compiling stopped. It doesn't finish. I want to `make` the pjsip project.